# understanding letter or digit function check in C

Tags: c, character

What do those functions check?

From what I understand, they are supposed to check if a word contains a non-alphanumeric character.
I don't understand how it does this.

#### My understanding:

- The first check is for the length - this is OK.
- The second check is if the character is a letter:
- `IsLetter(symbol[0]))` evaluates to FALSE. This is logically negated.
- The third function is the same as the above.

What I didn't understand, is the fourth one:
`IsLetterOrDigit(*symbol))`.

How does it check if the word has non-alphanumeric characters?

The code:

```
int IsSymbolValid(char* symbol)
{
    int len = strlen(symbol);
    
    if ((len == 0) || (len > MAX_SYMBOL_SIZE))
    {
        strcpy(LastParsingError, "Invalid symbol length");
        return 0;
    }

    if (!IsLetter(symbol[0]))
    {
        strcpy(LastParsingError, "Symbol name has to start with letter");
        return 0;
    }

    while (*symbol != 0)
    {
        if (IsLetterOrDigit(*symbol))
        {
            strcpy(LastParsingError, "Symbol name can contain only letters and digits");
            return 0;
        }
        ++symbol;
    }

    return 1;
}

int IsLetter(char ch)
{
    return (((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) || ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z')));
}

int IsDigit(char ch)
{
    return ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'));
}

int IsLetterOrDigit(char ch)
{
    return (IsLetter(ch) && IsDigit(ch));
}
```

Comment: Note the loop around the call to `IsLetterOrDigit`.

Comment: Why are you unportably reinventing [`isalpha`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/isalpha.html), [`isalnum`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/isalnum.html) and [`isdigit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/isdigit.html)?

Comment: Who on Earth writes his own functions instead of using `isdigit()` or `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: Your answer is invalid. Do you see beginners rewriting strcpy more often than not?

Comment: @H2CO3, Someone who wants to? Maybe to aid in their understanding?

Comment: @Shahbaz A beginner who doesn't bother using Google...

Comment: @AnishRam: In that case, IsLetter is unportable because it makes the assumption that 'a' + 1 == 'b', 'b' + 1 == 'c', ..., 'y' + 1 == 'z'. This is not the case when using the EBCDIC character set, and writing code by assumptions like this can be quite dangerous. Doesn't it now seem more likely that this would mislead people?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, I don't know about you, but I was taught `strcpy` right when I learned what strings are, but `isdigit` is something I realized existed long after I started programming. There are a lot of functions you wouldn't know exist as a beginner, for example `qsort`, `perror`, `strtol` (you learn `scanf` instead), `strchr`, `realloc` etc. Universities often simply move to C++, leaving you with just a basic knowledge of the C's standard lib (even though they may teach the internals extensively).

Comment: @Shahbaz: Universities also assume that students can (and should) research independently. How many brain surgeons do you know who learnt by trial and error?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, argue all you want. All I'm saying is that this is what happens, regardless of how it should be, or what is the ideal. That is why I answered _Who on Earth writes his own functions..._, with _a beginner_. The existence of these questions proves my point. Now instead of coming here all like "you're an idiot (to the OP)", try to understand his situation and help him. If you think he should have searched before asking (which I believe he should have too), simply state that, for example by saying a search for "bla bla" in google would have given your answer.

Comment: @Shahbaz Your suggestion is redundant; Can't you see that I already provided links to the results of such a search query? In addition, I made no assumptions at all, regarding the OPs intelligence or otherwise; Those are your words, not mine. I stated fact (that the OP is reinventing the wheel) and asked why.

Comment: @AnishRam I don't consider it wasting time or effort. If that's what you consider your time spent here, then perhaps it'd be a good idea to find something that you *really* want to do. The overall message was intended to convince the OP to research, in a broader fashion, regarding C... Not just to spoonfeed some information specific to one area of C.

Comment: @AmishRam It takes two to argue... The definition of *better* is too vague to give a clear meaning to your message. However, there's no point to this argument, so I'm going to agree that for the thousands of definitions of "better" that might make sense there, you're correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that this function is indeed wrong:

```
int IsLetterOrDigit(char ch)
{
    return (IsLetter(ch) && IsDigit(ch));
}
```

`&&` shows logical and, while a character cannot be both a digit and a letter. It should have used `||` (logical or):

```
int IsLetterOrDigit(char ch)
{
    return (IsLetter(ch) || IsDigit(ch));
}
```

---

While we are at it, it seems like there is also a bug where it is being used:

```
if (IsLetterOrDigit(*symbol))
{
    strcpy(LastParsingError, "Symbol name can contain only letters and digits");
    return 0;
}
```

You'd want the error if the characters is **not** letter or digit. Therefore (notice the `!`):

```
if (!IsLetterOrDigit(*symbol))
{
    strcpy(LastParsingError, "Symbol name can contain only letters and digits");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (*symbol != 0)
 {
  if (!IsLetterOrDigit(*symbol))
  {
   strcpy(LastParsingError, "Symbol name can contain only letters and digits");
   return 0;
  }


int IsLetterOrDigit(char ch)
{
 return (IsLetter(ch) && IsDigit(ch));
}`


so if i write this way the strcpy will be activated only if the char is not a ABC and not a number. right?

Comment: @Yuval, No, you completely ignored my first fix. Also, take a look at the [Demorgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), it's good for your understanding.

Comment: i know that it cant be also digit and number, this is why it can never return 1, but it can return 0 if they are both not numbers and not chars. if you put the || it will always return 1. no?

Comment: If it is both not a number and not a character, then `||` will return 0, because `0 || 0 = 0`. There's demorgan's law right in my last sentence: `not a number and not a character = not (a number or a character)`.